# Spring inject bean is always singleton

Tags: spring, spring-3

We are using spring 3.2.

We defined  a bean `myAccountVO` in `spring.xml` files and set the scope to `prototype`, but the spring creates this bean as singleton bean.

Here is the spring xml:

```
   <bean name="myAccountVO1"
        class="valueobject.AccountVO"
        scope="prototype" >
        <property name="accountNo" value="0105069413007" />
        <property name="accountType" value="01" />
    </bean>
```

The service class is:

```
@Service //I've tested the @Scope("prototype") but no luck
public class AccountSummary {


   @Autowired //I also tested @Resource but same result
   private AccountSummaryVO myAccountSummaryVO1;

  AccountSummaryVO  getAccount(){    
    return myAccountSummaryVO1
  }

}
```

Later we use this service as:

```
@Autowired
AccountSummary accountSummary;
............

accountSummary.getAccount()
```

As far as I get the `AccountSummary` class, itself, is a singleton and will not be instantiated every time.

It seems are very basic usecase, but I don't know what am I missing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are injecting `myAccountVO1`.

But I guess when you reveal the injected place that it's probably a member of a bean which itself is not in the scope prototype, e.g. @Service or @Controller. The service bean will be instantiated with a newly created `myAccountVO1`, but this instance stays there forever.

Change the scope of the containing bean. See [4.5.3 Singleton beans with prototype-bean dependencies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-sing-prot-interaction).

This applies as well to the beans which have the service beans injected.